# how to resize window with status bar in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a window that is in landscape mode. I have shifted my statusbar in landscape mode but the area where my statusbar was is still left white. I need to remove my window so that the area is filled. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Interface Builder, set the Status Bar attribute to None in your view (under Simulated Metrics in the Inspector), and it will stop believing it has a status bar. I don't know if this is the specific problem you're having without further information, but this has been the cause of white status bar areas for me in the past.